# define ssl_ciphers in nginx for each vhost

Tags: nginx, ssl

i`am just wondering if i define something like this:

```
ssl_ciphers 'AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL';
```

in my vhost config in nginx, it is active on all my vhosts which use ssl.

Is there a way to define the ssl_ciphers and ssl_protocols for each vhost separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_ciphers) states that the `ssl_ciphers` directive can be used both at `http` and `server` levels. So yes, when you specify it inside a `server` (virtual host) block, it applies only to that vhost.

Comment: You also could easily test it with https://github.com/jvehent/cipherscan tool by scanning different vhosts after setting them up.