# Can NGINX TLSv1.3 support the use of different cipher/hash/MAC for different server of same IP address?

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

I have two different domains - `thisdomain.com` and `portal.thisdomain.com`.  But only one public-facing IP address.

Each domains have their own SSL certificates but share same Intermediate CA.

Using the same IP address (and NGINX HTTP server has SNI support), I wanted to offer a different set of **TLSv1.2-only** cipher/hash/MAC for a different part of the website URL.

Is NGINX able to support different set of cipher/hash/MAC across:

- different subdomain of the same domain?

or/and

- different URL subdirectory of the same domain?

while using the same IP address?

In the example of different *domain*, is `https://portal.thisdomain.com/` capable of having its own cipher/hash/MAC set over `https://thisdomain.com`?

In the example of different URL *subdirectory*, is `https://thisdomain.com/portal` capable of having its own cipher/hash/MAC set over `https://thisdomain.com/`?

Comment: TLS 1.3? Did you come back in time from the future?

Comment: Fixed it.  It should read as 'TLS 1.2'.

Comment: Actually, Firefox and Chrome already support certain draft versions of TLS 1.3, along with Cloudflare :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The majority of your question is answered here: [define ssl_ciphers in nginx for each vhost](https://serverfault.com/q/669501/7709)

If your two sites are defined as different vhosts, then you can specify different ciphers for each one.

However, no, you absolutally cannot have sub-directories using different ciphers, as TLS has already been negotiated before the rest of the HTTP request (that includes the path) can be inspected.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I assume that this would rely on SNI to decide which configuration to use?

Comment: Sure, if you have both bindings on the same IP address. But you might not - you might have different IP address bindings for the different hosts. That would not require SNI to determine which binding to use.

Comment: Yes, of course. I specifically had the question in mind ("...for different server of same IP address?").

Comment: Ideally, `nginx.conf` would template as:

    http {
        server {
            listen thisdomain.com 443 http2 ssl;
            server-name thisdomain.com;
            root /var/www/vhosts/thisdomain.com/html;
            ssl-ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;;
        }
        server {
        listen thisdomain.com 443 http2 ssl;
            server-name portal.thisdomain.com;
            root /var/www/vhosts/portal.thisdomain.com/html;
            ssl-ciphers aNULL;
        }
    }
</pre>
And we use a SSL certificate with several domain names in its AltSubjectName field?